# Ajax onchange disables second ajax call onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I have situation where I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" onchange="javascript:ajax01()">
<a href="javascript:ajax02()">text</a>
```

Both ajax-functions work perfectly - except when I have the text-field active and click on the link. Then only `ajax01` is executed, not `ajax02`.

If I have textfield active, click outside the textbox, then `ajax01` fires, and then I click the link and `ajax02` fires. Both successfully.

But how do I get `ajax02` to fire simultaneously as `ajax01` if I click the link directly from being active in the frame?

Comment: It seems to be working, http://jsfiddle.net/YmZgT/1/

Comment: yes it seems... :( 

Then the error is somewhere else... I'll post back soon.  Thanks for the example!

Comment: Found the error - which was not completely logical! :(

I had a message wrapper that shows up under the displayed element, which hence moves the link downwards 50px. The click is then not catched on the link-object. So a displacement of an element can make an event not to trigger... didn't know that...

Answer (score 1):

Try this (notice I removed the `javascript:` from the input element. In my experience, this is only needed when used in a links `href` attribute. Also, there is no need to force the javascript into the `href` attribute. It should also be located withing an `on...()` function.

```
<input type="text" onchange="ajax01();">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajax02();">text</a>
```